# Viewing Rasters on Phone/Tablet with GPS Location?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, overlay

I have a Geotiff like the one below, and I'd like to be able to use it as a map I can view with my location on a table or smartphone. This can be via Google Maps or any other app.

That is, I can use this app and my phone's GPS to see where I am on this map. That way, I can send/share the maps with clients and they can view it on their property.

I don't need to be able to capture or work with the data in anyway. I just want an overlay with GPS location usable by a smartphone or tablet.

I have tried this with Google Maps, but as it can only work with vectors and I can't seem to get anything close to this image quality with a Vector it doesn't seem to work. And because I want clients to be able to use this, a $75 app like Guru Maps (that every client would have to buy) isn't a solution either.

I feel like there is an easy answer I haven't found yet.

[image: Geotiff image]

Comment: Google Earth Mobile (Free) will display this if embedded into a KML/KMZ, you can also use non-app https://earth.google.com/web and load the KML/KMZ into that if clients do not want to install the app.

Comment: QGIS mobile has been in development for quite some time https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qgis.qgis&hl=en_AU though I suspect there is more buttons and functions than you want for such a simple concept.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't realized Google Earth Mobile would accept KML overlays. So far this has worked well. Thanks Mapperz.